# Extracting the strings between the patterns and storing it in different files using Shell Script

Tags: shell

I am new to unix shell scripting. My goal is to extract a set of strings present between the lines "--------" and store each set of strings to different files.

Eg:
My file main.txt looks like

```
----------------------------
One
two
three
----------------------------
abc
four
five
-----------------------------
```

Expected Output:
String appearing in between the lines "----" has to be stored in different files like,

```
first.txt contains,
one
two 
three

Second.txt contains,
abc
four
five
```

Request your valuable help in this.

Thanks in advance,
Srikanth

Comment: Does this helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217399/split-input-into-multiple-outputs-based-on-content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i=0; file=$i.txt; cat tmp/t.txt |while read line; 
    do if [ "$line" = "----------------------------" ]; 
       then let "i=i+1"; file=$i.txt; continue; 
    fi; 
     echo  "$line" >> $file;
done
```

BTW, I use the shell only for interactive work. All coding gets done in Python.

You could use awk, too. But then you could use Python, Ruby, .... too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but am getting below error while exectuting it,`line 4: [: too many arguments` . Script looks like this,               `#!/bin/bash
i=0; file=$i.txt; cat temp1 | while read line
do
    if  [ $line == "---------------------" ]; then
        let "i=i+1"; file=$i.txt; continue
    fi
    echo  "$line" >> $file
done`